# Override part of the inherited controller method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, methods

i have a method in the first class

```
 class1
   def method(param_test)
     if !organization.empty?
       organization = test(param_test)
     end
    end
  end
```

Class 2 inherits from Class 1

```
class2  < class1

end
```

I would like to modify the line  `organization = test(param_test)`

without having to copy the whole method in the class2

it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the logic into two methods like this:

```
# in the parent class
def method(param_test)
  if !organization.empty?
    organization = fallback(param_test)
  end
end

def fallback(param)
  test(param)
end
```

And then just override the one method in the child class like this:

```
# in the child class
def fallback(param)
  # logic to return the expected response
end
```

An alternative might be to change the `test` method in the subclass. But how that might look like depends on the specific use case and the internals of the `test` method.